# CoreImage for Win32

Tags: opengl, image-processing, direct3d, core-image

For those not familiar with Core Image, here's a good description of it:
http://developer.apple.com/macosx/coreimage.html

Is there something equivalent to Apple's CoreImage/CoreVideo for Windows? I looked around and found the DirectX/Direct3D stuff, which has all the underlying pieces, but there doesn't appear to be any high level API to work with, unless you're willing to use .NET *AND* use WPF, neither of which really interest me.

The basic idea would be create/load an image, attach any number of filters that can be chained together, forming a graph, and then render the image to an HDC, using the GPU to do most of the hard work. DirectX/Direct3D has these pieces, but you have to jump through a lot of hoops (or so it appears) to use it.

Comment: HDC == low-level Windows API display context

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of tools for working with shaders (such as RenderMonkey and FX-Composer), but no direct equivalent to CoreImage.

But stacking up fragment shaders on top of each other is not very hard, so if you don't mind learning OpenGL it would be quite doable to build a framework that applies shaders to an input image and draws the result to an HDC.

Comment: It's RenderMonkey, not ShaderMonkey

Answer (score 0):

Adobe's new [Pixel Blender](http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Pixel_Bender_Toolkit) is the closest technology out there. It is cross-platform -- it's part of the Flash 10 runtime, as well as the key pixel-oriented CS4 apps, namely After Effects and (soon) Photoshop. It's unclear, however, how much is currently exposed for embedding in other applications at this point. In the most extreme case it should be possible to embed by embedding a Flash view, but that is more overhead than would obviously be idea.

There is also at least one smaller-scale 3rd party offering: [Conduit Pixel Engine](http://lacquer.fi/conduit/pixelengine.php). It is commercial, with no licensing price clearly listed, however.

Answer (score 0):

I've now got a solution to this. I've implemented an ImageContext class, a special Image class, and a Filter class that allows similar functionality to Apple's CoreImage. All three use OpenGL (I gave up trying to get this to work on DirectX due to image quality issues, if someone knows DirectX well contact me, because I'd love to have a Dx version) to render an image(s) to a context and use the filters to apply their effects (as HLGL frag shaders). There's a brief write up here:
[ImageKit](http://vcf-online.org/node/167)
with a screen shot of an example filter and some sample source code.